# Hide an element in the tables first row

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following table

```
<table id="mytable">
  <tr>
     <td>name</td>
     <td>
       <a id="button1" class="button">link</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td>name2</td>
     <td>
       <a id="button2" class="button">link</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to hide the first row first column button using jQuery, but I'm not sure how to do that, but I was manage to do the following (to make the first tr font italic).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytable tr:first").css("font-style", "italic");
});
```

Comment: to add css on first button you can use below code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have `id` of button, you can use id to hide it.

```
$('#button1').hide();
```

If you want to use `class` and can not using id for some reason, you can use [**find()**](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method to find the element within *descendants* fulfilling given selector criteria.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/fR7wt/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#mytable tr:first").find('.button').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

use this code

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#mytable tr:first #button1").css("display", "none");
    });
    </script>
```